# Embed forms in relation OneToOne

Tags: php, forms, symfony

sorry for my poor inglish, I have two entities called USER and DATA

Here the code of the USER entity:

```
    <?php

    namespace Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * User
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
     */

class User {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="usuario", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $usuario;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pass", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $pass;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Pedido", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $pedidos;

    /**
     *  @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Datos", mappedBy="personales")
     */

    private $datos;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set usuario
     *
     * @param string $usuario
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsuario($usuario) {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get usuario
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsuario() {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    /**
     * Set pass
     *
     * @param string $pass
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPass($pass) {
        $this->pass = $pass;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pass
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPass() {
        return $this->pass;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->pedidos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set pedidos
     *
     * @param string $pedidos
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPedido($pedidos) {
        $this->pedidos = $pedidos;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pedidos
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPedidos() {
        return $this->pedidos;
    }

    /**
     * Add pedidos
     *
     * @param \UTN\GuardaBundle\Entity\Pedido $pedidos
     * @return User
     */
    public function addPedido(\Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Pedido $pedidos) {
        $this->pedidos[] = $pedidos;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove pedidos
     *
     * @param \UTN\GuardaBundle\Entity\Pedido $pedidos
     */
    public function removePedido(\Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Pedido $pedidos) {
        $this->pedidos->removeElement($pedidos);
    }

    /**
     * Get datos
     *
     * @return string
     */

    public function getDatos()
    {
        return $this->datos;
    }

    /**
     * Set datos
     *
     * @param string $datos
     * @return User
     */

    public function setDatos($datos)
    {
        $this->datos = $datos;
        return $this;
    }




}
```

Here the code of the DATA entity:

```
    <?php

namespace Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Datos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\DatosRepository")
 */
class Datos
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="empresa", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $empresa;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cuit", type="integer")
     */
    private $cuit;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="localidad", type="string", length=50)
     */

    private $localidad;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="calle", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $calle;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="altura", type="integer")
     */
    private $altura;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="areaTel", type="integer")
     */
    private $areaTel;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telefono", type="integer")
     */
    private $telefono;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="areaCel", type="integer")
     */
    private $areaCel;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="celular", type="integer")
     */
    private $celular;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="datos")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Type(type="Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\User")
    */

    private $personales;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set empresa
     *
     * @param string $empresa
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setEmpresa($empresa)
    {
        $this->empresa = $empresa;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get empresa
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmpresa()
    {
        return $this->empresa;
    }

    /**
     * Set cuit
     *
     * @param integer $cuit
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setCuit($cuit)
    {
        $this->cuit = $cuit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cuit
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCuit()
    {
        return $this->cuit;
    }

    /**
     * Set localidad
     *
     * @param string $localidad
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setLocalidad($localidad)
    {
        $this->localidad = $localidad;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get localidad
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLocalidad()
    {
        return $this->localidad;
    }

    /**
     * Set calle
     *
     * @param string $calle
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setCalle($calle)
    {
        $this->calle = $calle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get calle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCalle()
    {
        return $this->calle;
    }

    /**
     * Set altura
     *
     * @param integer $altura
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setAltura($altura)
    {
        $this->altura = $altura;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get altura
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAltura()
    {
        return $this->altura;
    }

    /**
     * Set telefono
     *
     * @param integer $telefono
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setTelefono($telefono)
    {
        $this->telefono = $telefono;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telefono
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTelefono()
    {
        return $this->telefono;
    }

    /**
     * Set area
     *
     * @param integer $area
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setAreaTel($areaTel)
    {
        $this->areaTel = $areaTel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get area
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAreaTel()
    {
        return $this->areaTel;
    }

    /**
     * Set celular
     *
     * @param integer $celular
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setCelular($celular)
    {
        $this->celular = $celular;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get celular
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCelular()
    {
        return $this->celular;
    }

    /**
     * Set areaCel
     *
     * @param integer $areaCel
     * @return Datos
     */
    public function setAreaCel($areaCel)
    {
        $this->areaCel = $areaCel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get areaCel
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAreaCel()
    {
        return $this->areaCel;
    }

    /**
     * Set personales
     *
     * @param string $personales
     * @return Datos
     */

    public function setPersonales($personales)
    {
        $this->personales = $personales;
        return $this;

    }

    /**
     * Get personales
     *
     * @return string
     */

    public function getPersonales()
    {
        return $this->personales;
    }


}
```

The property that link User with Data is $data and the property that link Data with User is $personales.

I have a UserType and a DatosType:

Here the code of UserType:

```
  <?php

namespace Proyecto\LavocBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
    {
        $builder->add('usuario');
        $builder->add('pass');
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'user_form';
    }
}
```

and here the DatosType:

```
<?php

namespace Proyecto\LavocBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class DatosType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
    {
        $builder->add('empresa');
        $builder->add('cuit');
        $builder->add('localidad');
        $builder->add('calle');
        $builder->add('altura');
        $builder->add('areaTel');
        $builder->add('telefono');
        $builder->add('areaCel');
        $builder->add('celular');   
    }

    public function getName()
    {
    return 'datos_form';
    }

}
```

I have to make a form where they are the two forms. I would like to know how is the code to embed and as an actuary the controller to both generate the form and send it to the template as to receive data and store user data in a table called USER and save data DATA in the DATA table . Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UserType you can embed your DatosType like so:

```
->add('datos', new DatosType())
```

However in DatosType you should have data_class set like so:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Datos',
    ));
}
```

You should have a good read of the [forms documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) as almost all you need is in there.

Comment: Perfect, sorry for my poor inglish. I understand but how i create the form in the controller ?

Comment: Like I said above, all you need is here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html - the first two items deal with creating a form in a controller.